# Bash - cat several files with spaces in their name

Tags: bash, unix, cat

Let files="apartment.flat my apartment1.flat"

I want to cat those files using cat $files

The problem is cat searches for apartment.flat, my and apartmrnt1.flat

What do i need to do in order to escape those spaces?

I tried files="apartment.flat 'my apartment1.flat'"
And files="apartment.flat my\ apartment1.flat"
Nothing works...

Thank!

Comment: Read the [BashFAQ entry on Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments) (and then follow chepner's suggestion).

Answer (score 3):

You should use an array:

```
files=(apartment.flat "my apartment1.flat")
cat "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score -2):

you just need to put $files within quotes, should help you

> files="apartment.flat my apartment1.flat"
>
> cat "$files"

This worked for me

```
$ files="apartment.flat my apartment1.flat"
$ echo $files 
apartment.flat my apartment1.flat

$ cat "$files"
hi how are you..
```

Comment: Bash will still pass three arguments to `cat`: *apartment.flat*, *my*, and *apartment1.flat*